# обрезать записи длиной больше 128. postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
alter table finance_counterparty
alter column first_name type varchar(128);
```

делаю такой запрос, но получаю ошибку `django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(128)`
нужно обрезать все записи длинее 128. думаю нужно применить update вместо alter, но не понимаю как сделать коректное условие

Answer (score 0):

С помощью выражения `using` можно попросить `alter table` сделать преобразование

```
alter table finance_counterparty
alter column first_name type varchar(128) using left(first_name, 128);
```

Вот так получится:

```
melkij=> create temp table finance_counterparty (first_name text);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> insert into finance_counterparty select repeat('a', 200);
INSERT 0 1
melkij=> select max(length(first_name)) from finance_counterparty;
 max 
-----
 200
(1 строка)

melkij=> alter table finance_counterparty
alter column first_name type varchar(128) using left(first_name, 128);
ALTER TABLE
melkij=> select max(length(first_name)) from finance_counterparty;
 max 
-----
 128
(1 строка)
```

---

Обратите внимание, что данные свыше этих 128 символов вы так потеряете. Много раз проверьте, что вам именно это и нужно.

Comment: потеряю вообще или они станут обрезаны?

Comment: Будут оставлены первые 128 символов, последующие будут отброшены.

Comment: данные образало, но когда делаю pipenv run ./manage.py migrate все равно получаю ошибку django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(128)

Comment: Покажите SQL, который даёт ошибку

Comment: operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("""
alter table finance_counterparty
alter column first_name type varchar(128) using left(first_name, 128);
"""),
        migrations.RunSQL("""
alter table finance_counterparty
alter column last_name type varchar(50) using left(last_name, 50);
"""),

Comment: хм. Покажите теперь по логу базы, что именно этот запрос даёт ошибку, а не какой-то другой.